# Passing Sockets Through Navigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, sockets, reactjs, components, react-native

I keep getting that `undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.socket.on)`. I declare my socket in my `index.ios.js` file like so:

```
class Main extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        message: ''
      };
      this.socket = io('http://localhost:8000', {jsonp: false})
 }
```

Then, in my `renderScene(route, navigator)` method for navigation, I have:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
   if (route.id == 'EnterName') {
     return <EnterName socket={this.socket} navigator={navigator} />
   }
}

render() {
  return (
    <Navigator
       initialRoute={{id: 'EnterName', index: 0}}
      renderScene={ this.renderScene } />
  );
}
```

But this socket information is not being properly passed into EnterName. I get the error above when I try:

```
this.props.socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
   this.state.messages.push(msg);
   this.forceUpdate();
});`
```

Do you know why the socket isn't being initialized/passed correctly?

Comment: I think this.renderScene should be this.renderScene.bind(this)

Comment: What would that do? Could you break it down very slowly for me?

Comment: It has to do with scope of 'this' in javascript. Inside a function 'this' refers to the function itself, But to access the properties of the Main Component inside the renderScene function 'this' should refer to the Main Component. When you use bind, it creates a new function and set its this value to the value provided, here we provide reference to (this) the Main Component while binding. See more here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind .

Comment: Continuing... This is a classic javascript newbie gotcha. Everyone goes through this.  Check out this article as well. http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/  .  What G. Hamaide is suggesting is the new syntax of writing functions that has been introduced in ES6 version of javascript. It is called arrow functions. See more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

This is **gr3x** btw.

If you toss a **debugger** at the start of the **renderScene** and you inspect **this** you will see that you are in a different scope, the **Navigator**'s scope, and you do not have access to **this.socket** which exists in **Main** so you are passing **undefined** to **EnterName** as the **socket** prop and why you are receiving these errors when accessing it from **EnterName**

Instead, add **this.socket** to the **initialRoute** object, and access it in the **renderScene** via **route** like so

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.id == 'EnterName') {
     return <EnterName socket={route.socket} navigator={navigator} />
    }
}

render() {
  return (
    <Navigator
       initialRoute={{id: 'EnterName', index: 0, socket: this.socket}}
       renderScene={ this.renderScene } />
  );
}
```

That should resolve your issue. Let me know on reddit if I can be of further assistance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a context issue I think. You should specify your render method with es6 fat arrow :

```
renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
   if (route.id == 'EnterName') {
     return <EnterName socket={this.socket} navigator={navigator} />
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have time to explain this in-depth -- the arrow method and the context issue? A friend suggested I scrap Navigator altogether in favor of Ex-Nacigator, and that I use Flux as well. Could you talk about the pros and cons of that?